# Control Toolbox: How does the function minreal work in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, controls

I have a question about the function “minreal” in Matlab. From the help of Matlab I would assume that the output is a minimal realization of a system. To my understanding it means that the output function is observable and controllable.

Example:

```
num = [ 6.40756397363316, -4511.90326777420, 7084807.91317081, -3549645853.18273, 2307781024837.00, -761727788683491, 2.26760542619190e+17, -1.54992537527829e+19, 5.58719150155001e+21 ];
den = [ 1, 824.614362937241, 1036273.19811846, 592905955.793358, 319582996989.696, 106244022544031, 2.87990542333047e+16, 2.36284104437760e+18, 3.50241006466156e+20, 0];
G = tf(num,den);
G_min = minreal(ss(G));
```

But it is not a minimal realization:

```
>> size(G_min)
State-space model with 1 outputs, 1 inputs, and 9 states.
>> rank(obsv(G_min))
ans =     6
>> rank(ctrb(G_min))
ans =     5
```

So obviously: rank(obsv(G_min)) != rank(ctrb(G_min))  != 9 (number of states).

Where is my mistake?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually you are correct, in that a minimal realization is controllable and observable.  However, [minreal](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/minreal.html) makes no guarantees of that.  As per the doc:

```
Pole-zero cancellation is a straightforward search through the poles
and zeros looking for matches that are within tolerance. Transfer functions
are first converted to zero-pole-gain form.
```

That is, `minreal` just does a somewhat mindless search for whether poles and
zeros are *close* to each other, and makes no guarantees that the result
satisfied any other conditions.  Note that in your case you could specify a
larger tolerance and more states would be eliminated,

```
>> G_red = minreal(G,10)

G_red =

      6.408 s + 74.87
  ------------------------
  s^2 + 625.7 s + 1.703e05

Continuous-time transfer function.
```

and you'd get something closer to what you might expect.

Alternatively, you'd most likely be better off transforming to a balanced realization and deciding which states to eliminate yourself.  See the doc for [balreal](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/balreal.html) for an example of how to use it with [modred](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/modred.html) to achieve this.

You might also take note of the doc for [obsv](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/obsv.html), which clearly states that you shouldn't trust its results for anything other than toy problems:

```
obsv is here for educational purposes and is not recommended for serious control design.
Computing the rank of the observability matrix is not recommended for observability testing.
Ob will be numerically singular for most systems with more than a handful of states.
This fact is well documented in the control literature. For example, see section III in
http://lawww.epfl.ch/webdav/site/la/users/105941/public/NumCompCtrl.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go now step by step through your detailed answer. (I tested also the controllability and observability of my function with gram's matrix, because in one of my books there was also some hints that obsv and ctrb are not numerical stable. But the result was the same.)

Comment: The hint with balreal/modred helped me a lot. May I ask you a further question? Do you have any idea, why s=tf('s');K=(s^2+47.06*s+18405)/(s^2+25.72*s+29771) is mathematically a stable controller for the given plant, but in reality the system becomes unstable? I tested successfully several controllers before which also damp these poles and zeros. Multiplying K with a small factor did not make it stable.